# Remove all `at` jobs

Tags: command-line, at

I know that to remove a scheduled `at` job I have to use `atrm "numjob1 numjob2"`, but is there an easy way to do that for all the jobs?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can run this command to remove all the jobs at the atq

```
 for i in `atq | awk '{print $1}'`;do atrm $i;done
```

Comment: variation on this answer `at -l | awk '{printf "%s ", $1}' | xargs atrm `

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like this:

```
for i in $(atq | cut -f 1); do atrm $i; done
```

Comment: In FreeBSD it's `cut -f3`
First column is date

Answer (score 9):

This seems to me a short line:

```
atrm $(atq | cut -f1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For more AIX 6 systems you can simply do:

```
atrm -
```

Ref: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds1%2Fatrm.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here is my xargs version that avoids braces and is hopefully intuitive:

```
atq | cut -f 1 | xargs atrm
```

You can also grep specific jobs by timestamp/userid and then remove them:

```
atq | grep "2018-10-22 16:" | cut -f 1 | xargs atrm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had more than 58k jobs in the atd (someone rebooted the server and for some reason atd service not started). Removing the jobs using atrm is very painful for very high queue.

I stopped atd and deleted all dirs from **/var/spool/atjobs** and files from **/var/spool/atspool** . For me it worked.

```
rm -rf /var/spool/atjobs/* ; rm /var/spool/atspool/*
```

Comment: You never say anything about starting up `atd` again, and whether that was successful, nor do you mention what Unix this would be an adequate solution for. How did you make sure that other users' jobs were not deleted?

Comment: Ok! Sorry!
Need to start atd after the process.
My solution is for "SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12". But I think it can use in other distributions. I found the information of directories in "man".
In my situation, only root is using atd, then removing the files was safe.