# Kill all queued jobs

Tags: shell, arguments, at

I need to kill all the queued and running jobs on my ID. I have tried

```
   at -l | awk '{print $1}'| at -r {}
```

But I keep getting

```
   {} does not exist
```

Which leads me to believe that I am parsing the statement wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` pipes the output to the standard input of the next command, not to its command line arguments.

To remove all queued jobs, run

```
at -l | awk '{print $1}'| xargs at -r
```

alternatively, you can use

```
at -r  $( at -l | awk '{print $1}' )
```

`$( ... )` is replaced by the output of the commands it contains.

See also [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53144/15241).

Please note, that this just removes the jobs from atq, but does not kill running jobs.

If the processes command line matches to a PATTERN and there are no other similar processes running on your username, you can kill them with

```
pgrep -u $USER PATTERN
```